# Way to get SQL statement to be quicker

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there a way to speed up the performance of this query.
I have indexes on tswProjectID and tswWeekEdning.

This SQL was generated from my Linq statement which is
what I want to use in my C# code.

Is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
var qry = (from tsw in TimesheetWeeklies where tsw.TswProjectID == 8263 select tsw).OrderByDescending(x => x.TswWeekEnding).FirstOrDefault();


SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[tswID] AS [TswID]
FROM [TimesheetWeekly] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[tswProjectID] = 8263
ORDER BY [t0].[tswWeekEnding] DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Try create an index with both columns in it (tswProjectID, tswWeekEnding)

Answer (score 1):

It wont make the query any faster but if you make it a compiled query you could possibly save some time that it takes to build the query if it's done more than once, more info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx